# I found this bug in my closet. Could someone help me identify?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

It looks like it recently died. The shell was shiny and smooth and fairly brittle. I've been having trouble identifying what it is because it doesn't quite look like any of your common house pests.

The bug is at most 4 mm. I live in a relatively old apartment in New York City and my best guess is that this guy crawled out of a crack in my closet wall.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Can you please add 1) approximative scale 2) where do you live (country and lower scale information about the ecology around your place) 3) How is your house (do you live in an old wooden house or in a modern concrete building)?

Comment: I've updated the original post. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I agree This is definite a spider beetle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image you provided isn't the best of quality, but I *really* think it looks like a **[spider beetle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider_beetle)**. Anyone else agree?

[image]

Comment: I looked up a few more images of these guys and I think you're right on the money.

Comment: Glad to hear it, and best of luck when trying to get rid of them!